# How to get rid of navigation bar for iOS for the first screen of application

Tags: ios, navigationcontroller

I am confused about navigation controller, My first View in the application consists of 4 buttons inside, I wanna add a navigation controller to this view so where I push another views to navigation controller according to which buttons is pressed and I can see navigation bar on other views I am redirected.

However I dont want to see the navigation bar on the top for the first view. Is there a way for adding the navigation controller to appdelagete and make the navigation bar not visible for my first screen.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add navigation bar in your app

Use following code in `didFinishedLaunching:withOptions:` of `AppDelegate` class:

```
ViewController *homeController = [[HomeController alloc] init];
self.controller = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController];
[self.window addSubview:self.controller.view];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

In the `ViewController`'s `viewWillAppear` method, Add the following line of code:

```
[[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:NO];
```

In the `ViewController`'s `viewWillDisappear` method, Add the following line of code:

```
[[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:NO];
```

Comment: Thanks Viral; There is a small problem though; when I add setNavigationBarHidden:YES, it hides the navigation bar however it hides the navigation bar for the other views I am directed also. Do you have an idea how can I solve that ?

Answer (score 1):

Put this below code in your **viewWillAppear** method to get it called everytime when you return on the first view

```
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:NO];
```

and put

```
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:NO];
```

in viewDidLoad of next controller you want to push or, you can also place the above code in **viewWillDisappear** of FirstViewController.